# FFT - radio between harmonic

Tags: matlab, math, fft

I'm trying to calculate ratio between harmonic (5/1 and 7/1) on this signal:
[image]

My FFT code is:

```
figure()
fs=1000;
L=length(UI_przebiegi.signals.values(:,7));
NFFT1 = 2^nextpow2(L);
f=fs/2*linspace(0,1,NFFT1/2);
y=fft(UI_przebiegi.signals.values(:,7),NFFT1);
plot(f,abs(y(1:NFFT1/2)))
```

`UI_przebiegi.signals.values(:,7)` is vector. So how to calculate this ratio?

Comment: Can you give more explanation about what you want to calculate?

Comment: @Adiel First, 5th and 7th harmonic.

Comment: Ok, and what do you mean "ratio"? between peaks? between bandwidths? between energies?

Comment: Ratio between peaks.

Comment: To find peaks you can use `findpeaks`, or use `diff`, searching where it changes its sign.